# Can't get files from public folder because of route

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express

I am having problems with getting my js/css files from the public folder, i think it's because of my routes but i am not sure...

when my webpage loads, I get the next errors:

`GET http://localhost:3000/ <view-file> /javascripts/ <js/css-file> net::ERR_ABORTED`

my files are included like this:

`<script src="javascripts/<file>.js"></script>
<script src="stylesheets/<file>.css"></script>`

the thing is that, i use the same method in all my views files and i don't get this problem

i think it's because the way i make my route for that view:

```
router.get(['/', '/:invID'], function(req, res, next) {
   if (!req.params.invID){
      // check if there is an invitation code
   } else {
      // here is an IF inviation code is invalid
        if ( // invite code invalid){
            // code....
        } else {
           // invite code is valid so render the view
            res.render('register', {
                title: 'Express',
                invID: req.params.invID,
                userData: // user data object
            });
        }
    });

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why it works, but i fixed it by adding an "/" before the javascript folder

`<script src="/javascripts/<filename>.js"></script>`

i have 4 other views without the "/" and they work without problems...  wierd

Comment: The leading backslash makes the path root-relative. A good strategy for debugging is to look into the network tab of your browser dev tools and see what's _actually_ being loaded. In this case I imagine you'd see `/:invId/javascript/...`.

Comment: yea, root-relative makes sense, but still in the other views it doesn't have problems ( i changed them anyway)
and in the dev tools it wasn't `/:invId/javascript/...` it was just `localhost/<view>/javascript/...` it didn't care about the `invId`
thanks for the advice